# how to call a jquery click function using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wand to call a jquery click function using JavaScript

```
<input type='button' class="button" value='+Add' id='addImage'>
```

when i click this button the following function will run

```
$("#addImage").click(function () { 
    //my code.....
 }
```

but i need to call this function using another JavaScript function like fn_name()

Comment: Just use `$("#addImage").trigger('click')`

Comment: Thanks its working @Satpal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `trigger` and the name of the event, like so (the example below uses a self-executing function for simplicity):

```js
$("#addImage").click(function() {
  alert('Clicked')
});

(function(){
  $("#addImage").trigger('click')
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' class="button" value='+Add' id='addImage'>
```

Comment: No worries, if this answer is one that solved the problem then please select as Accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$("#addImage").trigger("click")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. declare function
2. bind click event
3. call function

```
     //declare
    function test(){
        //my code.....
    }


    function callTest(){
       // call function
       test();
    }


    function callAClick(){
      //trigger
      $("#addImage").trigger('click')
    }

    // bind click
    $("#addImage").click(test);
```

Comment: Plis, add some explanation, why it helps.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

you have this ugly way too, but not recommended:
https://jsfiddle.net/96oxhwsf/

```
function fn_name() {
  $("#addImage").click(function() {
    alert('test')
  });
}

fn_name()
```

beatiful way:

```
function fn_name(elID) {
  let btn = document.getElementById(elID);
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Test');
  }, false)
}

// still need call the function
fn_name('addImage');
```

even better:

```
var addImg = () => {
  let btnAdd = document.getElementById('addImage')
  btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert('test')
  }, false)
}
```

Comment: OP's request was for a jQuery answer...  Anyway, since you didn't check the return value of document.getElementById you might just as well have written it as a 1-liner: `document.getElementById('addImage').addEventListener('click', () => { ... }, false);`